# It it safe to backup a column in the same UPDATE statement?

Tags: mysql

Is it safe in INNODB to backup a column first to another column, before setting a new value? I have tried it and the columns seem to be processed in the specified order, but is this guaranteed? If not, is there another solution without executing two UPDATE statements?

```
UPDATE tab SET a_prev = a, a = 2
Before: a = 1
After: a_prev = 1, a = 2

UPDATE tab SET a = 2, a_prev = a, 
Before: a = 1
After: a_prev = 2, a = 2
```

Comment: What is the point of the second update?  Shouldn't it be `SET a = a_prev`, to restore the original value of `a` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen This was for demonstration purposes only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html)

> If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression,
> UPDATE uses **the current value** of the column. For example, the
> following statement sets col1 to one more than its current value:
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;
> ```
>
> The second assignment in the following
> statement sets col2 to the current (updated) col1 value, not the
> original col1 value. The result is that col1 and col2 have the same
> value. **This behavior differs from standard SQL.**
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

When UPDATE is performed then the row is used as a buffer. If some expression alters the value then this new value is placed into the row and old value is lost, so the next column usage will apply altered value.

> the columns seem to be processed in the specified order, but is this guaranteed?

Yes. The expressions are evaluated in the order in which they are provided in the query text. Without this the documented behavior is impossible, it should become non-deterministic.